# Prove that the language of regular expressions is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

I want to prove that the language of all regular expressions is not a regular language. I'm having trouble to approach this problem. I thought maybe to show that the parenthesis language is a part of it, and then I can rule out the regularity.

Comment: "The parenthesis language is a part of it". Have you thought about all regular expressions like $(^na)^n$?

Comment: A more interesting question might be about regular expressions in reverse polish notation where no parentheses is needed.

Comment: @JohnL. Hardly. $a^{n+1}+^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work: if you may assume that the language of matching brackets is non-regular, it suffices to know that whenever a language is regular, erasing all occurrences of a particular character from all of its words produces a regular language. That isn't very hard to prove.